# Can we Use .env variable inside the httpCredentials inside playwright.config.js file

Tags: playwright, dotenv, playwright-test

I want read httpCredential value from env file in Playwright.  is there any way to use variable .env variable inside httpcrdential in playwright.config.js.
installed dotenv

dotenv.config({
path:`./env/.env.dev`
})

and inside httpCredential

```
httpCredentials: {
  username: `${process.env.USERNAME}`,
  password: `${process.env.PASSWORD}`
}
```

Comment: What you have done looks right. Is it not working?

Comment: Are you able to console.log these env values from cnfig file?

Answer (score 0):

.env file:

```
MY_USERNAME=abc
MY_PASSWORD=123
```

config-file:

```
  use: {
    httpCredentials: {
      username: process.env.MY_USERNAME ?? 'cant find username',
      password: process.env.MY_PASSWORD ?? 'cant find password',
    },
  }
```

Just don't use an env-variable named USERNAME or PASSWORD, it has to be something different (at least in my case). Perhaps it's because there are already variables of the same name inside httpCredentials {}